# What level of math do you need to start studying quantum mechanics?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, education, advice

What level of math is needed to start teaching yourself quantum mechanics? I was studying griffiths textbook and it says that nothing will be too complicated in the beginning, but what does "complicated" mean?

Answer (score 4):

From a search for *Griffiths quantum mechanics prerequisites*:

> Griffiths: You should have a solid background in calculus, ordinary
>   differential equations, basic partial differential equations, and a
>   little bit of Linear Algebra. I suggest you do all of the problems in
>   this book as they are very helpful for understanding the math of
>   quantum mechanics.

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-prerequisites-to-learn-Quantum-Physics-What-are-the-best-sources-for-learning-them

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/griffiths-quantum-mechanics-prerequisites.831599/